# Google Maps Javascript API - google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am creating a map using the Google maps api and can't get past the "google is not defined" error.

My html:

```
<script defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;></div>
```

Js:

```
let map;
var user_area={lat:50.909698,lng:-1.404351};
function initMap(){
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{center:user_area,zoom:10,});
}

var properties=[
  ["prop_9451", "51.62712097168", "-0.38445112109184","1"],
  ["prop_9428", "51.622886657715", "-0.41938832402229","2"],
  ["prop_5476", "51.649826049805", "-0.38144716620445","3"],
  ["prop_10212", "51.518814086914", "-0.34517586231232","4"]
];

var marker,y;
for(y=0;y<properties.length;y++){
  marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:properties[y][1],lng:properties[y][2]},map:map});
}
```

The map loads fine but the markers don't with the "google is not defined" error coming on the following line:

```
marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:properties[y][1],lng:properties[y][2]},map:map});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you need to use `google` needs to happen **after** `initMap` is called.

So you can do something like this:

```js
let map;
var user_area={lat:50.909698,lng:-1.404351};
function initMap(){
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),{center:user_area,zoom:10,});
  setupProperties(); // call the function from in here
}

var setupProperties = () => {
  var marker,y;
  for(y=0;y<properties.length;y++){
    marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:{lat:properties[y][1],lng:properties[y][2]},map:map});
  }
}
```

EDIT: I'm sure this question is a dupe, I just can't find a good one right now - if anybody can find one that has a good answer, please close this question.

The reason for this is because google maps is loaded `asynchronously`. It's not ready - i.e. there is no `google` variable - until `initMap` is called. Therefore, whenever you need to access `google.maps.XXX` it needs to happen **after** `initMap` is called, otherwise, you'll get the error.